# Rails 5: Convert Time.zone (e.g "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" ) into a numbered offset (e.g -0700)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, ruby-on-rails-5

This is an ongoing issue I'm having and I don't know how to work with it.

A user sets their `Time.zone` when they create an account. In this case "Pacific Time (US & Canada)".

When they create an object and enter in the date and time it comes in the format of a string with no explicit timezone offset like so "05/31/2017 2:00 PM"

Knowing these two things. I would like to convert the inputted time string into a UTC format and save it.

I've tried the following but it's  not taking the pacific time into account:

```
time = Time.strptime("05/31/2017 2:00 PM Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z").utc
=> 2017-05-31 14:00:00 UTC
```

14:00:00 UTC is 7AM pacific. It should be 21:00:00 as it is currently -0800. I would like to find a method to take timezones into account and save them correctly in UTC format.

It however converts correctly if I give it the exact offset like so:

```
time = Time.strptime("05/31/2017 2:00 PM -0800", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z").utc
=> 2017-05-31 22:00:00 UTC
```

This problem is killing me. I would simply like to save all date and times in UTC format so all that a user has to do is set their timezone and view times correctly. Also taking into account DST if applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you can use ActiveSupport to change a time zone without changing value and convert to utc

```
#parse time as usual
time = Time.strptime("05/31/2017 2:00 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")

#convert to utc using timezone that you need
res = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('Pacific Time (US & Canada)').local_to_utc(time)
#> 2017-05-31 21:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: That worked! I can now convert and save times as UTC and the conversion work correctly.